# Visual Studio stopped rebuilding dependent projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Suddenly, Visual Studio 2010 has stopped behaving as it used to:

I have a solution containing several projects: a Class Library project, an Application project and a Test project.

The Application project is set as default startup project.

Now if I change anything in the Class Library and press F5, Visual Studio does not rebuild the Class Library anymore, so that it runs outdated code.

Same behaviour with the Test project.

What am I doing wrong? I am pretty sure this type of behaviour is new, but I do not know what I have changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the solution explorer, right click on the solution name and go to "Configuration Manager.."
You will see the active solution configuration. Select which project to build or not by turning the checkbox on or off. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great! Seems this was the problem.

Comment: Found various duplicates, but this is the only correct answer. +1